# Is there any way to style a view with alternate row having a similar pattern in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

Kindly, find the picture below. This is the way I would like to modify my view

[image]

I am trying to style my view in which all the even rows have a particular format and all the odd rows have a different format. But I am not able to find any correct way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the code you have written so far? You could e.g. use the index of the row in the array of rows to decide how it should look. `rows.map((row, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? <SomeRow /> : <AnotherRow />)`

Comment: I just started learning ReactNative. I do not know where to start from.@ Tholle

Comment: That's alright. When you have written some code and if you can't figure it out, you can include the code in the question and @ me and we can take a look.

Comment: Sure,I will do that @Tholle